# Debugging code in C

Tags: c, debugging, output

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code and why it is producing this output.

Code:

```
int main(){
  unsigned num;
  char response;

do{
 printf("Please enter a positive integer greater than 1 and less than 2000: ");
 scanf("%d", &num);
 if (num > 1 && num < 2000){
    printf("All the prime factors of %d are given below: \n", num);
    printPrimeFactors(num);
    printf("\n\nThe distinct prime factors of %d are given below: \n", num);
    printDistinctPrimeFactors(num);
 }
 else{
    printf("\nSorry that number does not fall between 1 and 2000.\n");
 }
 printf("\n\nDo you want to try another number? Say Y(es) or N(o): ");
 getchar();
 response = getchar();
}
while(response == 'Y' || response == 'y'); // if response is Y or y then program runs again
printf("Thank you for using my program. Good Bye!\n\n"); //if not Y or y, program terminates
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter a positive integer greater than 1 and less than 2000: 1600
All the prime factors of 1600 are given below: 
2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 

The distinct prime factors of 1600 are given below: 
2 5 

Do you want to try another number? Say Y(es) or N(o): yes
Please enter a positive integer greater than 1 and less than 2000: All the prime factors of 1600 are given below: 
2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 

The distinct prime factors of 1600 are given below: 
2 5 

Do you want to try another number? Say Y(es) or N(o): Thank you for using my program. Good     Bye!
```

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with it! *The prime factors of 1600 are 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, and 5*

Comment: yeah...if you see when i type "yes" is where it goes strange

Comment: not the actual code for the prime factors...but what the output produces from the user input

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in a debugger to see what's going on?  Hint - `getchar()` only reads a single character.  What does that leave on the input stream when you call `scanf()` again?  Hint 2 - check out [`fgets(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/).

Comment: @CarlNorum My professor (yes this is "homework") wanted us to use getchar() for this assignment. Using scanf would resolve this issue, right? However, I have to use getchar()...

Comment: @mikemikee `getchar()` consumes 1 character from `Yes`, leaving `es` on the input stream. Give it `Y` or `N` as input, or prepare to handle the cases `yes` and `no`.

Comment: Then you need to put those `getchar()` calls in a loop and wait for `\n` characters to show up before re-looping.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask whether you want to repeat, you only read the `y`, leaving the `es` queued up in stdin. When you go to read the next number, `scanf` tries to parse that as a number, fails, and returns without altering `num`.  When you prompt the user, you need to burn that whole line.